# How to set a row for editing on a button click in GridView

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview

I had a GridView which contains some `DataGridTextColumn` and one `DataGridTemplateColumn` which has a button control.

```
<DataGrid Name="dgProductList" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          RowBackground="{StaticResource MainBackground}" RowHeight="30"
          GridLinesVisibility="None" IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Id}" Header="Id" Visibility="Hidden" 
                            FontFamily="verdana"  />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" Header="Name" 
                            FontFamily="verdana"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Amount}" Header="Amount" 
                            FontFamily="verdana"  />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Name="btnEdit" Width="117"  Style="{StaticResource GlossButtonStyle}" 
                            Click="btnEdit_Click" >Edit</Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

By default user is not allowed to edit this gridview.

**Requirement is**

1. When user click the edit button in the row , that particular row only needs to be enabled for editing, rest of the rows should be locked from editing.
   Further on click of that button only editing should be available not on the click of gridview cell.
2. Then that extra row should not be there by default and i had a button outside of grid, on click of that new blank row has to added to the gridview and available in edit mode.

I blocked Editing and avoid blank row by using `IsReadOnly="True", AutoGenerateColumns="False"`. Rest thing i didn't get how to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create ViewModel for each row and add IsEditing property to it. You can start with something like this:

   ```
   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
       <Grid>
           <ToggleButton x:Name="btnEdit" IsChecked="{Binding IsEditing,Mode=TwoWay}">Edit</ToggleButton>
           <TextBox Visibility="{Binding IsEditing,Converter=yourfavorite}" 
                       Text="{Binding Path=., Mode=TwoWay}"/>
       </Grid>
   </DataTemplate>
   ```

To keep only one active row you can reset IsEditing for all RowViewModels except the current.

2. Your external button handler will invoke AddNewRow() method on Grid's viewModel.

}

```
class RowViewModel
{
    GridViewModel parent;
    public RowViewModel(GridViewModel parent)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Amount { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public bool IsEditing 
    {
        get { return this == parent.ActiveRow; }
        set 
        { 
            if (value) 
                parent.ActiveRow = this;
            NotifyChange();
        }
    } 
}


class GridViewModel  
{  
    private RowViewModel activeRow;  
    public ObservableCollection<RowViewModel> Rows { get; private set; }

    public GridViewModel()
    {
        Rows = new ObservableCollection<RowViewModel>();
    }

    public void AddNewRow()
    {
        Rows.Add(new RowViewModel(this) { IsEditing = true });
    }

    public RowViewModel ActiveRow 
    {
        get { return activeRow;}
        set 
        {
            activeRow = value;
            foreach (var row in Rows.Except(new[] { activeRow })) 
            {
                row.IsEditing = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```